# Can I use any library or Scipy in Python for 4 or n dimensional interpolation?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

I've searched a lot on the internet but haven't found an exact method. If someone can point me to a library that can do this, that would be great.
I want to find a 4-dimensional cubic spline function such that f(A, B) = C,D.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called `CubicSpline` in `scipy.interpolate`.